# Getting countdown to count correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Hey all i have this code posted here: **http://jsfiddle.net/mN6Gy/12/**

Problem is it skips numbers in the seconds (goes from 30, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15,...)

and once the seconds reach 00 it start back over on 99, 98, 97, 96...!!

Any help to find this in the code would be great!

Thanks,

David

Comment: I'm thinking it is something to do with your (Conditional) max digits block of code - the logic must be flawed since it apparently is always giving a max 'seconds' 2nd digit of 5 (so you get 21...20...15) and a max 1st digit of 9 - which we all know is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, this is was not fun to debug - and I'm not sure I have all the answers...

The issue I found is that you have too many days so your indexes are off.

```
Options.format: "dd:hh:mm:ss"
> Actually have '119:01:16:18' (for example)
```

So when you are looping through, all your indexes are off by one - for now. But when the time gets to <100 days, it would be right - I think.

As a hacky solution to see what I mean (and so you may have a place to start the fix), see this editing snippet:

```
    switch (options.format[i]) {
      case 'h':
        digits[c].__max = ((c-1) % 2 == 0) ? 2: 9;  // <== EDIT
        if (c % 2 == 0)
          digits[c].__condmax = 4;
        break;
      case 'd':
        digits[c].__max = 9;
        break;
      case 'm':
      case 's':
        digits[c].__max = ((c-1) % 2 == 0) ? 5: 9;  // <== EDIT
    }
```

Comment: By the way, it may be helpful to set the interval to 100ms for testing - you can still see what it is doing well enough and it will cycle through minutes in a more reasonable time frame.

Comment: That part of the code seemed to correct the 95 issue. Thanks, Josh! :o) Updated code on jsFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, the code seems to run fine - after `x` seconds, the counter counts `x` less. The `setInterval()` function in your code

```
setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1000);
```

calls `moveStep()` every 1000 miliseconds, i.e. every second. However, you cannot expect your computer, your operating system and your browser to be totally precise with miliseconds. Sometimes the event triggers sooner and sometimes it triggers later (especially if you are also running other programs that may interfere or slow down your code). So it just may happen that instead of

```
counter=2 - 1 second delay - counter=1 - 1 second delay - counter=0
```

you get

```
counter=2 - 2 second delay - counter=1 - counter=0
```

or something like that. In this case, you wouldn't see the `counter=1`, because it gets immediately redrawn when the next event triggers and `counter` is set to `0`.

One thing you can do is to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, so you get

```
var callback = function() {
    moveStep(digits.length - 1);
    setTimeOut(callback, 1000);
}

setTimeOut(callback, 1000);
```

In this case, the timed events won't line up in a queue and then trigger at once, like they did in the previous case. This is because you don't set the interval, but just a timeout - the next event is scheduled to occur 1 second after the current event has finished. This way, the time between two events will always be (approximately) 1 second.

However, the problem here is with the world approximately. In the first case, `setInterval()` schedules the events to occur 1 second, 2 seconds, 3 seconds etc. from now, so after `x` seconds, your counter should be decreased by `x`, although it sometimes doesn't redraw at every step. However, in the second case, when using `setTimeout`, the little deviations from 1000 miliseconds may slowly build up, so your counter will get decremented by `x*1.1` after `x` seconds, or something like that. In other words, you can't guarantee it to be on time.

To sum it up, you're facing a common problem with `setInterval` and I don't think there is much to do about it.

Comment: If you look and watch, you will see that it does it EVERY time - 21...20...15, 11...10...5, etc. That's not a timer question but a code question, in this case something to do with the indexing while looping and setting the 'max' value per digit